# Let $C'$ be normalization of singular curve $C$. Does $C(K)\neq \emptyset$ imply $C'(K)\neq \emptyset$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, arithmetic-geometry

Let $K$ be a number field or finite field. Let $C$ be a singular curve defined over $K$.
Let $C'$ be normalization of $C$ and $\phi : C'\to C$ be normalization map.

It is well known that this map $\phi$ is surjective (for example, [Stacks 035E](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035E)), and $\phi $ is defined over $K$.
Then, does $C(K)\neq \emptyset$ imply $C'(K)\neq \emptyset$・・・① ?

But in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4669518/rational-point-on-normalized-curve-and-original-curve), Sasha reads we can construct counterexample of ①.

So I'm confused. Why ① does not hold in spite of $\phi$ is surjective and defined over $K$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this does not hold. Here is a counterexample: let $C=\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$, which has normalization $C'=\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q[t,u]/(u^2+1)$. Then $C(\Bbb Q)=\{(x,y)\}$  while $C'(\Bbb Q)=\varnothing$.

The reason your desired claim doesn't hold is that if $p\mapsto q$ for a map of schemes $f:X\to Y$, we have a map of residue fields $k(q)\to k(p)$. This means "size limitations" only go one way - if $k(p)$ is "small", then $k(q)$ must be as well; if $k(q)$ is "big" then $k(p)$ must be too (being a $k$-rational point of a $k$-scheme is in some sense the most strict "smallness" limitation). For instance, if $X$ and $Y$ are $k$-schemes, $f$ is a $k$-morphism, and $p$ is a $k$-rational point, then we have a map $k\to k(q)\to k(p)$ where the composite $k\to k(p)$ is an isomorphism, which forces $k(q)\cong k$ as well.

Comment: Thank you. Are there any known sufficient conditions ? For example, if $C'$ is genus 1 curve over finite field, are there still counterexample ?

Comment: I can't think of any general criteria off the top of my head. Sasha's counterexample will work just fine in that case you mention too - take any such curve with no $k$-rational points, glue a Galois orbit, and voila, a singular curve with a $k$-point whose normalization has no $k$-points.

Comment: @R.P. you'll need to add an [@reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to ping the OP, otherwise the notification generally only goes to the author of the answer.

Comment: @masquerade There are sufficient conditions, although it rather depends on what kind of conditions you are looking for. For example if the normalization is a bijection on points (over the algebraic closure) then trivially a K-point on C implies a K-point on C′. This is not as facile as it sounds, because this condition can be checked on the local ring of the singular point, even I think on the completion of the local ring (although I'm fuzzy on the details). However, clearly this condition is not necessary.

Comment: @KReiser Thanks :)

Comment: @KReiser I think Sasha's counterexample does not work here because $C'$ is genus $1$ smooth curve, so it should have $k=\Bbb{F}_q$ rational points.

Comment: @R.P. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/035E , lem 29.54.5 reads map $\phi : C'\to C$ is surjective. Doesn't this imply $K$ point on $C$ implies $K$ point on $C'$ ?

Comment: Ok, sure, so my last comment doesn't apply because I picked from the empty set :) Anyways, your question in your post has been answered - if you want to ask a different question or alter the hypotheses, you should make a new post. (PS: my answer above contains an example of a normalization where $C(k)\neq\emptyset$ but $C'(k)=\emptyset$, so I don't understand why you're asking R.P. the same question - just read the answer!)

Comment: @KReiser  I mean, surjectivity of $\phi$(which is defined over $K$) contradicts an example ,  ''$C(k)\neq \emptyset$ but $C'(k)=\emptyset$''. So I'm confused. Maybe I misunderstand the lem 29.54.5 of stacks.. ?

Comment: @masquerade Surjectivity does not imply surjectivity on $k$-points without more assumptions. Consider, for instance, $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q(i)\to\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Q$: this is surjective (both underlying topological spaces are 1 point) but the former doesn't have any $\Bbb Q$ points.